# AES Missing Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, rijndaelmanaged

I'm using AES on WP8 (Windows Phone 8) in C# on Visual Studio, and System.Security.Cryptography does not contain the attribute 'Mode' for AESManaged.

I've looked up this problem for the past 3 days now, and haven't found any reference or anything to import.

The code I am currently using is:

```
            AesManaged cipher = new AesManaged();
            cipher.BlockSize = 8;
            /*cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.None;*/
            //cipher.KeySize = 128;
            //cipher.FeedbackSize = 8;  
            cipher.Key = key;
            cipher.IV = key;
            return cipher;
```

While the BlockSize throws an exception 'Specified block size is not valid for this algorithm.'

I was originally using RijndaelManaged but that isn't available on WP8 *but* according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) it should be available.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight verison of AES have no mode property. Here is [MSDN article about that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

"The AES algorithm is essentially the Rijndael symmetric algorithm with a fixed block size and iteration count. This class functions the same way as the .NET Framework RijndaelManaged class but limits blocks to 128 bits and does not allow feedback modes.
**The cipher mode is always CBC**, and the **padding mode is always PKCS7**."

You can extract AES from [BounceCastle library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) if you need more modes and flexibility. I did that before.

Comment: Hi, @crea7or this isn't supported for WP8

Comment: ***UPDATE*** I had added the reference BUT when I go to do `using WP8BouncyCastle;` it says that the reference does not exist.

Comment: Don't know where the problem in your case. However, maybe [Crypto++  library](http://developer.nokia.com/blogs/community/using-crypto-library-with-windows-phone-8-featured-article-windows-phone) will work better in your project?

Comment: I'll try that; but it's not really building correctly. A lot of errors coming up.

Comment: Is there a C# way to make WP8 apps without Silverlight?

Comment: c# ways is: 1) AesManaged 2) BounceCastle 3) [Windows Phone RT Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aspx) (available in 8.1). Why not to exctract AES code from bounce castle? Here is the code of AES in BC library "\bccrypto-net-1.7-src\csharp\crypto\src\crypto\engines", additionally you'll need a few more files to support AES modes and Paddings. It's not hard at all.